# Stanford NER CRF model is giving different results on CMD and in Code

Tags: stanford-nlp, named-entity-recognition

I have made my own CRF model by following this link.
http://nlp.stanford.edu/software/crf-faq.shtml

**Command for training** is:
**java -cp stanford-ner.jar edu.stanford.nlp.ie.crf.CRFClassifier -prop austen.prop**

Then I test this model on CMD by following this **testing command**.
**java -cp stanford-ner.jar edu.stanford.nlp.ie.crf.CRFClassifier -loadClassifier training-ner-model.ser.gz -testFile testing_data.txt**

This produces results on console.

Then I am using this model programmatically in my code and giving same sentence which is in test file. This is **not giving same results as produced by that testing command**.

I searched a lot why this is behaving like this but found nothing till now. Can anybody help me in this regard, I will be thankful to you.

Comment: Please post the code that you are using to run the model programmatically.

Comment: @JonGauthier
There is my code.

String serializedClassifier = "training-data-ner-model.ser.gz";
AbstractSequenceClassifier<CoreLabel> nerClassifier = CRFClassifier.getClassifier(serializedClassifier);

String sentence = "There I wrote my required test sentence."
String xml = nerClassifier.classifyToString(sentence, "xml", true);

After getting this xml I am just parsing it and results are different.
(I have also checked the xml by just printing it, its results are different from that of CMD results)

Comment: How are the two results different?